# Speed processing improvement by using tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    class ProcessedEven
    {
        public int ProcessedInt { get; set; }

        public DateTime ProcessedValue { get; set; }
    }

    class ProcessedOdd
    {
        public int ProcessedInt { get; set; }

        public string ProcessedValue { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        IEnumerator<int> enumerator = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000).GetEnumerator();
        Dictionary<int, ProcessedOdd> processedOddValuesDictionary = new Dictionary<int, ProcessedOdd>();
        Dictionary<int, ProcessedEven> processedEvenValuesDictionary = new Dictionary<int, ProcessedEven>();

        stopwatch.Start();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            int currentNumber = enumerator.Current;

            if (currentNumber % 2 == 0)
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    ProcessedEven processedEven =
                        new ProcessedEven { ProcessedInt = currentNumber, ProcessedValue = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(currentNumber) };
                    await Task.Delay(100);

                    processedEvenValuesDictionary.Add(currentNumber, processedEven);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    ProcessedOdd processedOdd =
                        new ProcessedOdd { ProcessedInt = currentNumber, ProcessedValue = Math.Pow(currentNumber, 4).ToString() };
                    await Task.Delay(100);

                    processedOddValuesDictionary.Add(currentNumber, processedOdd);
                });
            }
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

So basically I have to iterate over an enumerator that is all the time synchronous.

Once the current value from the iterator is taken it gets processed, somehow in a way that takes a long time. After is processed depending on its value is being added to a dictionary. So in the end the dictionaries have to be populated with the right values.

In order to improve the speed I thought that introducing some parallelism could help, but after adding the "Task.Run" calls some

> "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

exceptions occured. Also the execution time increased compared to the "synchronous" version of this code (the one without the "Task.Run" calls).

I do not understand why these exceptions are being raised since everything seems not to be null.

Is there a way to improve the speed in this scenario (original code is without the "Task.Run" calls) by using multi threading ?

Should the addition of the processed elements to the dictionaries be done inside a lock statement, since the dictionaries seems to be shared between the tasks ?

Comment: You are creating a lot of small tasks and exhausting your thread pool by calling `Task.Run`. You better use [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.8) for better performance. And as @user1672994 said you should use thread safe version of `Dictionary` - `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: Not sure what you are measuring but It is not the 100ms of `Task.Delay(100)` since you are not awaiting it. You can remove it or actually await it.

Comment: @Peter Bons, I just forgat to await them, since usually the await methods ends their names with "Async". I also updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a lot of small tasks and exhausting your thread pool by calling Task.Run. You better use [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.8) for better performance. And as @user1672994 said you should use thread safe version of `Dictionary` - `ConcurrentDictionary`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    IEnumerable<int> enumerable = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000);
    ConcurrentDictionary<int, ProcessedOdd> processedOddValuesDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ProcessedOdd>();
    ConcurrentDictionary<int, ProcessedEven> processedEvenValuesDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ProcessedEven>();

    stopwatch.Start();

    Parallel.ForEach(enumerable,
        currentNumber =>
            {
                if (currentNumber % 2 == 0)
                {
                    ProcessedEven processedEven =
                        new ProcessedEven { ProcessedInt = currentNumber, ProcessedValue = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(currentNumber) };
                    // Task.Delay(100);

                    processedEvenValuesDictionary.TryAdd(currentNumber, processedEven);
                }
                else
                {
                    ProcessedOdd processedOdd =
                        new ProcessedOdd { ProcessedInt = currentNumber, ProcessedValue = Math.Pow(currentNumber, 4).ToString() };
                    // Task.Delay(100);

                    processedOddValuesDictionary.TryAdd(currentNumber, processedOdd);
                }
            });

    stopwatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I also don;t understand why you need `Task.Delay(100)` in your code. Anyway it is async operation that without `await` operator would do something that you probably don't expect. Ether use await or use sync version `Thread.Sleep(100)`

Comment: By using Task.Delay(100) I tried to increase the processing time, to simulate a time expensive operation.

Comment: @Clock, without 'await' you are not really simulate what you want. Your task will end at the moment it hits Task.Delay

Comment: Good point about the await. I read your answer and you proposed a parallel for each, still the enumerator is all the time synchronous does not have a &quot;GetItemsAsync&quot; method. So in this case, does it make any sense to use the parralel for each ? I will give it a try when I am back to the PC to see if execution time improves.

Comment: @Clock you can't use `async` inside `Parallel` library methods. You should parallelize only **CPU-bounded** work. Async work is **IO-bounded** it means it doesn't performed by CPU (eg by disk controller or network socket). Hence utilizing more cores won't improve performance. To make better suggestion we need more info about your real work that should be improved.

Comment: The application that I want to improve is iterating over an enumerator. Than is creating some new objects from the enumerator's objects and based on their types is adding the newly created objects to their corresponding dictionaries. Anyway if, as  @user1672994 said, the key of an item may jump to another item this speed improvement won't be used. In the end those dictionaries will be serialized but that is running quite fast, the operations inside the enumerator are slow when creating those new objects that are added to dictionaries.

Comment: How the enumerator is created? What is the source? What operation performed in the loop? It is I/O or CPU?

Comment: Inside the loop are performed some CPU operations, math calculations. The enumerator is just read from a third party API and I do not have access to its implementation. I suppose that also when using Parallel implementation the dictionary key may get a different value, now I am testing,

Comment: So for CPU work `Parallel.ForEach` will be the best solution. But if enumeration creation is async and performed by reading many elements one-by-one you could use Producer-Consumer pattern and perform your CPU work while reading data from 3rd party or using `IAsyncEnumerable` (C# 8 feature). If it is still not enough you will need to profile your code and find bottle necks. It can be objects/arrays creation, then you will need to use some object pool.

Comment: Great, I just tested and the parallel for just got a 10 times faster time than the Task.Run approach. I also modified a little the code so that I can test the keys and values from dictionaries by setting the same value in key and in  "ProcessedValue " from the  dictionary value and all the time the values were ok, so I could not reproduce the problem  @user1672994 was saying, do you know something about this key/value mismatch problem inside of a concurrent dictionary ?

Comment: He is talking about reader-writer race condition as a concept. Since your code only writes data, you won't face this issue.

Comment: For this example the parallel for was much faster than the Task,Run approach, still against the first synchronous implementation was just a little faster, probably because the operations were taking few time, kind of exhausting you was talking about in the begining, I will try this approach tomorrow on the real thingy.

Comment: Ok, so I will have to read about this concept, still not knowing too many about threads...  Yes, the application first will just write to those dictionaries when iterating over that enumerator. Then serializes the dictionaries and later  is deserializing and only reads them. Thanks a lot, you made my evening !

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) which is a thread-safe collection of key/value pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently.

`ConcurrentDictionary` is designed for multithreaded scenarios. You do not have to use locks in your code to add or remove items from the collection. However, it is always possible for one thread to retrieve a value, and another thread to immediately update the collection by giving the same key a new value.

When I ran your code after changing `Dictionary` to `ConcurrentDictionary` then code runs without `NullReferenceException` and finished in ~1.37 seconds.

**Full Code :**

```
    class Program
    {
        class ProcessedEven
        {
            public int ProcessedInt { get; set; }

            public DateTime ProcessedValue { get; set; }
        }

        class ProcessedOdd
        {
            public int ProcessedInt { get; set; }

            public string ProcessedValue { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            IEnumerator<int> enumerator = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000).GetEnumerator();
            ConcurrentDictionary<int, ProcessedOdd> processedOddValuesDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ProcessedOdd>();
            ConcurrentDictionary<int, ProcessedEven> processedEvenValuesDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ProcessedEven>();

            stopwatch.Start();

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                int currentNumber = enumerator.Current;

                if (currentNumber % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        ProcessedEven processedEven =
                            new ProcessedEven { ProcessedInt = currentNumber, ProcessedValue = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(currentNumber) };
                        Task.Delay(100);

                        processedEvenValuesDictionary.TryAdd(currentNumber, processedEven);
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        ProcessedOdd processedOdd =
                            new ProcessedOdd { ProcessedInt = currentNumber, ProcessedValue = Math.Pow(currentNumber, 4).ToString() };
                        Task.Delay(100);

                        processedOddValuesDictionary.TryAdd(currentNumber, processedOdd);
                    });
                }
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I will give it a try once back to PC.

Comment: The parallel for moves faster than my approach with Task.Run.Still I can not reproduce the problem you're saying with the key/value mismatch in a concurrent dictionary. I changed the "ProcessedValue " to int in both classes and then assign those some values like "ProcessedValue = (int)Math.Pow(currentNumber, 1)" and ProcessedValue = (currentNumber + 1). After the dictionaries where populated I tested the key/value matching by iterating the dictionaries (checking like "if (item.Key != (item.Value.ProcessedValue - 1)) then problem"), but no problem was found. Do you know how can I reproduce it ?

Answer (score 2):

The specific reason you are getting the `NullReferenceException` is because the internal state of a `Dictionary` container became corrupted. Probably two threads have tried to resize the two internal arrays of a `Dictionary` in parallel, or something else equally nasty. Actually you are lucky that you get these exceptions, because a far worse outcome would be to have a working program that produces incorrect results.

The more general reason of this issue is that you have allowed parallel ansynchronized access to thread-unsafe objects. The `Dictionary` class, as most built-in .NET classes, is not thread-safe. It is implemented with the assumption that will be accessed by a single thread (or at least by one thread at a time). It contains no internal synchronization. The reason is that adding synchronization in a class incures API complexity and performance overhead, and there is no reason to pay this overhead every time you use this class, when it's only going to be needed in a few special cases.

There are many solution to your problem. One is to keep using the thread-unsafe `Dictionary`, but ensure that it will be accessed exclusively by using locks. This is the most flexible solution, but you need to be very careful to not allow even a single unprotected code path to the object. Accessing **every** property and **every** method, either reading **or** writing to it, must be inside a [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement). So this is flexible but fragile, and may become a performance bottleneck in case of heavy contention (I.e. too many threads are requesting the exclusive lock concurrently, and are forced to wait in a line).

Another solution is to use a thread-safe container like the `ConcurrentDictionary`. This class ensures that its internal state will never become corrupted when accessed by multiple threads in parallel. Unfortunately it ensures nothing about the rest of the state of your program. So it is suitable for some simple cases that you have no other shared state except from the dictionary itself. In these case it offer performance improvements because it is implemented with granular internal locking (there are multiple locks, one for every segment of data).

The best solution is to remove the need for thread synchronization alltogether by eliminating the shared state. Just let each thread work with its internal isolated subset or data, and only merge these subsets when all threads have been completed. This usually offers the best performance, at the cost of having to partition the initial workload and then write the final merging code. There are libraries that follow this strategy but are dealing with all this boilerplate, allowing you to write as fewer code as possible. One of the best is the [TPL Dataflow library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), which is actually embedded in the .NET Core platform. For .NET Framework you need to install a package to use it.